# How can I change the way filetype is set from the "#lang" directive in Racket

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype

I have some Racket programms that begin with the specification of a dialect

```
#lang plai-typed

#| racket code goes here ... |#
```

When I open these files with Vim, `filetype` is set to `plai-typed`. That is a
problem because it breaks syntax highlighting.

If I delete the line that contains `#lang`, then  `filetype` is set to `racket`
and syntax highlighting works as expected.

Why is Vim setting the `filetype` that way? How to stop that without deleting the line with `#lang`?

Comment: This behavior is coming from [here](https://github.com/wlangstroth/vim-racket/blob/master/ftdetect/racket.vim). You can probably work around it by setting `g:racket_hash_lang_dict` in your vimrc (takes precedence over that one) that includes a `plai-typed` key mapping to `racket`. (I'd also copy the rest of the dict entries to keep the behavior for those `#lang`s too in that case.) I see that @D.BenKnoble pushed the last commit to that file, so wondering if he'd like to expand on handling of `#lang` for Racket?

Comment: Could also be using my version of the plugin https://github.com/benknoble/vim-racket My version supports better overrides, IIRC. The `hash_lang_dict` approach is correct. I'll have to elaborate more later, but if you use my fork you won't need to keep all the other entries as they get merged in.

Comment: thank you guys! that's correct, thanks for the workardound. If you answet the question I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: I've made some edits, but if you will please [edit] and mention the plugin you were using, that will improve the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this is my fault :)

As I explain [here](https://github.com/wlangstroth/vim-racket/issues/62):

> This is at least partially my fault; I advocated for this on the basis that not all `*rkt` files are actually racket, and the racket syntax shouldn't try to highlight them all.

> OTOH, `br` is now correctly mapped to racket, and it's trivial to add `sicp`/etc. (My fork adds, for example, `info` and `info/setuptab`, which it supports. My fork also supports the new `jsond` language, but it doesn't need extra configuration precisely because of the new mechanism.)

> See `g:racket_hash_lang_dict` in `ftdetect/racket.vim`. It would be nicer to merge the user's config with the defaults, but I didn't do that yet as I haven't needed it.

Fortunately the global variable is extensible.

Depending on which version of the plugin you use:

- for the `wlangstroth` fork, use

```
:let g:racket_hash_lang_dict = { 'plai-typed': 'racket', <all the default values here> }
```

- for the `benknoble` (my) fork, use just

```
:let g:racket_hash_lang_dict = { 'plai-typed': 'racket' }
```

Since my fork supports merging the current value with defaults. My fork also has a few other tweaks and overridable variables, as well as general improvements. It also gets updated more often.